# How to map a Pandas series to objects in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{type: "FeatureCollection",
"crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OCG:1.3:CRS84" }},
"features": [
    {"type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
    'BDYSET_ID': 9,'ED_ABBREV': 'ABW','ED_ID': 85,'ED_NAME': 'Abbotsford West','FEAT_AREA': 104653208.2437,'FEAT_PERIM': 47130.005,'GAZETTE_DT': None,'OBJECTID': 86},
    "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[ 1.11111, -1.11111]]]
    }
    }
]}
```

And I have a pandas series from a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df['Winner'] = 0 A
               1 B
               2 A
               3 C
               4 B
               5 A
```

How do I change the values of all 'BDYSET_ID' objects in the JSON to match the letters in the  `df['Winner']` by index?

For example, I did
`data['features'][0]['properties']['BDYSET_ID'] = "A"`, which works but only replaces the value of one 'BDYSET_ID' object. How do I do this for all of them based on the index?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't this be done with a for loop?

```
for i, value in zip(df.index, df.Winner):
    data['features'][i]['properties']['BDYSET_ID'] = value
```

Comment: I tried this:
`for i in len(data['features']):
    data['features'][i]['properties']['BDYSET_ID'] = df['Winner'][i]`
but got an error that integer objects are not iterable.

Comment: I just tried what you said and it worked, thank you for your help!

Comment: Cheers. Your for loop would need a `range( )` wrapped around the `len()` integer. Python is cool because objects are ofter iterable, allowing us to avoid the use of `range` in many cases